# JSON contains multiple arrays

Tags: c#, json

```
 private T GetResponse<T>(string queryUrl)
 {
     UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(queryUrl);

     using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = new Uri(uri.Uri.AbsoluteUri), Method = HttpMethod.Get })
     {
         
         var responseMessage = httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
      

         if (!responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             var message = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

             throw new InvalidOperationException($"Error: {responseMessage.StatusCode} Message: {message}");
         }
                   
            var responseJson = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var response = DeserializeObject<List<T>>(responseJson);
            return response[0];
       
     }
    
 }
```

The code above will get the first item (return response[0]) in the JSON array.  The number of items could vary , so how do I get all of them?
For example, I can get the second item by  (return response[1])..etc

Comment: How about just declaring `GetResponse` to return a `List<T>` instead of `T`?

Comment: Using `.Result` instead of `await` will cause deadlocks. You should fix that.

Comment: DeserializeObject into <T> instead of <List<T>>, so the caller can decide if they want a list or a single T.

Comment: Many thanks sweeper
All recommendations were good but for the time being, returning List<T> seems to work for me.